# Next.js not loading file inside

Tags: reactjs, next.js

js and i am trying Next.js and this is my directory

[image]

and in counter-state.js

I have this code:

```
import {useState} from "react";

function UpdateCounterButton(props){
    return <div>
        <button onClick={props.updateCount(value=>value+1)}></button>
    </div>
}

function CounterRender(props){
    return <div>{props.count}</div>
}

export default function CounterState(){
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0)
    return(
        <>
        <CounterRender count = {counter} />
        <UpdateCOunterButton updateCount = {setCounter}/>
        </>
    )
}
```

Then i run

```
yarn dev
```

when i go localhost:3030

it opens next's page

[image]

and when i go localhost:3030/counter/counter-state

it gives 404 error

[image]

any help please what i am doing wrong !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Next 13 To be able to make this path work, the structure must be this: Inside `app`, a folder `counter`, inside this add other folder `counter-state` and within this folder add a file named `page.js`

[image]

You can take a look here for more info https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing